# Trivy unable to take into account the semver version override in package.json

Tags: vue.js, package.json, semantic-versioning, package-lock.json, trivy

Trivy scanner is unable to take the updated version(7.5.2) and still throws error in the build(showing installed version as 7.5.1).

## (alpine 3.17.4)

Total: 0 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 0, HIGH: 0, CRITICAL: 0)

## Node.js (node-pkg)

Total: 1 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 1, HIGH: 0, CRITICAL: 0)

┌───────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│        Library        │ Vulnerability  │ Severity │ Installed Version │ Fixed Version │                           Title                           │
├───────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ semver (package.json) │ CVE-2022-25883 │ MEDIUM   │ 7.5.1             │ 7.5.2         │ semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service │
│                       │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2022-25883                │
└───────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Made following changes to override the semver version to bypass the Trivy scanner to accept a fixed version (7.5.2).

Changes were done in package.json

"overrides": {
"semver": "^7.5.2"
},

and

"resolutions": {
"semver": "^7.5.2"
},

When I tried to run ‘npm i’ in my local environment and searched for all occurrences of semver in package-lock.json ;
Under the packages, "semver": "^7.5.2" version got updated.

Comment: I believe that you should explicitly list `semver` inside your `devDependencies` in `package.json` and also try `npm list` so see which package(s) is using the outdated `semver`